# How do you make a control reusable in different projects?

Tags: vb.net, code-reuse

Is there a way to not put the project name in the Inherits attribute?

I am working with vb and I have multiple projects, that have multiple web pages.
In each of these projects I create controls that are reused in the web pages.

Each control I have is declared like this:

`<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MenuBarControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="**projectName**.MenuBarControl" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>`

When I want to copy the control into another project I have to change the `**projectName**`.
Having to change the project name for each project makes the code not reusable. Changes made to specific projects each time is not reusable.

I want to be able to omit the project name in the Inherits attribute. 
When I do that now I get an error

`Parser Error`

`Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MenuBarControl'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new project that includes all the controls, reference that from the web projects.

Comment: This was quite possibly the most simple answer. Thank you for the help. It took me a while to make sure I had the project created in the correct location. The correct location is To put it in the inetpub/wwwroot/procject folder.  Well for me at least. Then I have to change all of the inherits to the name of the project I just created. ie. Inherits="WebProject.MenuBarControl -> Inherits="ControlLibrary.MenuBarControl" Then last we make sure ControlLibrary is in WebProjects ie. WebProjects\ControlLibrary

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2005/10/30/487160.aspx

Basically, you create a DLL and include it in your other projects. Alternatively, you can modify a user control library. More info here: http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the Help with the Link. It was most helpful in finding out where to put the new project.